# Problem exporting blender model to substance painter, Marmoset and sketchfab

Tags: export

When i export this model in as an .obj and import them into the other software the meshes get all mest up. I recalculated the normals and made sure is facing out but nothing fixes it. Also i used other models i had to test and they all work fine so i don't know why this model in specific is giving me problems.
[image: In Marmoset the mesh is all mest up]
[image: And in Substance painter the mesh is facing inside]
Weird thing is when i flip the normals (they look darker) and import it into SP it looks fine. So i guess the reason i'm having the problem might be the normals but i don't know. also in sketchfab the model becomes transparent.

Comment: Here's my blend file http://www.filedropper.com/spawnresurrectiongreatsword

Answer (score 1):

It seems it was the mesh itself, there were some vertices that weren't connected, making the mesh act like that when exported to other software. So went back took a good look and connected some vertices and cleaned the mesh, that fixed the problem.